# How to get the current Id of a user to pass to _Layout ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to pass the Id of the current user to the _Layout master page.

It must be passed to where "asp-route-id"

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="MyPersonalCabinet" asp-route-id="HERE">My Cabinet</a>
```

Here is the method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyPersonalCabinet(string id)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
        
    if (user != null && userId == id)
    {
        return View(user);
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

With `var userId = _userManager.GetUserId (HttpContext.User);` I get the current id in the method. How do I do something like this to pass this Id to _Layout

I tried to come up with something with ViewBag but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try injecting userManager in the layout.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
```

Then retrieve Id

```
<p>@{var user = userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
           var userId = user.Id;} </p>
```

Comment: I've tried this way already. Identity doesn't have a method like Id. Name and IsAuthenticated only

Comment: My bad. Not with my computer, so I couldn't test. I updated the answer, try if this would work. There could syntax issues in it

Comment: Did you get this working? Stuck on the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to write inside the _layout:

```
{
@using System.Security.Claims;
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext

@{
    var userId = _httpContext.HttpContext.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var username = _httpContext.HttpContext.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
}

<p>ID: @userId</p>
<p>UserName: @username</p>
}
```